# Generate a list of timestamps in format HH:mm:ss for 24 hours with Python

Tags: python, timestamp

How to generate with Python built-in tools a complete list of timestamps in format HH:MM:SS for 24 hours, saved in a text file?

The result should look like this:

00:00:00

00:00:01

00:00:02

00:00:03

... 86364 results in between...

23:59:58

23:59:59

Comment: I'd start by using 3 (nested) *for* loops (outer -> inner: hour, minute second), generate the string from the 3 variables and write it in the file.

Comment: @Fran Doesn't even require the use of any actual `datetime` objects…

Comment: What have you tried, where are you stuck? There is no technical issue or question here, merely a task description for a fairly trivial task.

Answer (score 1):

Use **timedelta** to update datetime object.

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

start = datetime.now().replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)

for i in range(24*60*60):
    temp = start+timedelta(seconds=i)
    print(temp.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
```

Comment: Thank you, @Mazhar! Use of .replace() was the key to the solution.